# Why does it still prompt me for missing return statement

Tags: java, return

Well i surrounded my return statement in a try catch block, so i can make sure the entered text is String because the method needs a return of string, however i still get an error that it needs a return statement when it's there!

```
    public String getBatchName(){
    try {
        return textField1.getText();
    } catch(InputMismatchException i){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "You have entered illegal characters for the batch name!"
        );
    }
}
```

new code :

```
    public static String getBatchName(){
    try {
        return textField1.getText();
    } catch(InputMismatchException i){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "You have entered illegal characters for the batch name!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
        );
    }
    return textField1.getText();
}
```

Comment: What does it return if you get an exception in `getText()`?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't return anything if an exception is caught.  Include another `return` statement after the `catch` block to handle the case where you caught an exception and the other `return` never executed successfully.

Comment: ... or just don't catch the exception, and let it propagate up.

Comment: @rgettman i updated my first post, does this code function then with the output after testing ?

Comment: @Boolena: Sure. The last return statement will always throw an `InputMismatchException` if reached, but your code is valid and will compile.

Comment: That won't work well, because either that call worked the first time in the `try` block, or it didn't work and it'll throw the exception again.  Either return `null` to indicate that there was a problem with the input, or don't catch the exception, and let the caller handle the exception as @JonSkeet has suggested.

Comment: @Keppil alright, but i want the user to know that it threw an InputMismatchException, not me.

Comment: @Boolena: To clarify, it will work, but won't make much sense. Your best bet is to follow jonskeet's or rgettman's advice.

Answer (score 0):

You will never get any exception while calling `JTextField#getText()`

```
 textField1.getText();
```

hence there is no point of handing any exception.